# Breaking out of a foreach loop in Velocity

Tags: syntax, velocity

I am using

```
#if( $velocityCount > 5 )
    #break
#end
```

to break my `foreach` loop, but its not breaking instead it is printing `#break` in the output.

I also tried:

```
#foreach($item in $group.shipItems) 
    #if( $velocityCount > 5 )
        #item.break
    #end
#end
```

Here also it is printing `#item.break` instead of breaking the loop.

Comment: Which version of velocity are you using? `#break` was introduced in version 1.6.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using version 1.6, then `#break` should suffice. This makes me think you are using 1.4 or 1.5. Or are you seeing some errors?

If you are using version 1.7, `#break` should still work, but you could be specific and do

```
#foreach($item in $group.shipItems) 
    #if( $foreach.count > 5 )
        #break($foreach)
    #end
#end
```

Please make it a habit to specify version when asking questions.

Comment: Your are right. In 1.7 both `#break` and `#break($foreach)` work.